# limit having definite Integration

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Finding $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg(\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(by+a(1-y)\bigg)^xdy\bigg)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ (Where $b\neq a$)

what i try

$\displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}\bigg[by+a(1-y)\bigg]^xdy = \frac{\bigg(by+a(1-y)\bigg)^{x+1}}{x+1}\Bigg|^{1}_{0}$

$$=\frac{b^{2}}{2}-a$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: You made an error in the computation of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let $u = by + a(1-y) = (b-a)y+a$ then $du = (b-a)dy$ so
$$
\int_0^1 (by+a(1-y))^x dy
 = \int_a^b u^x \frac{dy}{b-a}
 = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b u^x du
$$

Can you finish this now?